# Segregated IDistributedCache DI Consumption

Tags: c#, caching, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am implementing the IDistributedCache interface through DI within my application, and it works as expected.

The only problem is that since this is a cache shared throughout the application, a developer writing caching code may not necessarily know what keys were used in the rest of the application (or maybe even other applications connecting to the same distributed cache).  For example, let's say I want to cache Users by using the key: "UserId:{userId}".  Another developer in other module, decides he also wants to cache Users, and he comes up with the same key.  Wouldn't these two conflict with each other?

I was hoping there was something similar to the ILogger pattern, where you can only resolve ILogger by providing a category type.  Similarly in IDistributedCache, the "key prefix" would be automatically injected, thus solving such potential conflict issues.

In DI constructor, you could then do stuff like this:

```
public MyClass(IDistributedCache<GlobalCache> globalCache, IDistributedCache<MyClass> myClassCache) { ... }
```

"GlobalCache" is a class you'd need to create, which is awkward.. but I'm just trying to think out loud here so maybe someone can pitch in with alternative ideas to solve this issue.

Comment: You can write a wrapper over `IDistributedCache` implementation like `MyDistributedCache<T>`. That class should be injected with `IDistributedCache` as `MyDistributedCache(IDistributedCache distributedCache)`. Now, the implemented class can use T to generate the `Key Prefix`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement and inject the `IDistributedCacheFactory`, not the instance of `IDistributedCache`. Then in the dependent instance, you call `CreateCache` method of the factory which will provide the caller with the correct instance. Something like

```
public DependentClass(IDistributedCacheFactory cacheFactory){

   this.cache = cacheFactory.CreateCache("MyApplicationCategory");
}
```

I suggest not to use the class name in the cache prefix. If the class gets renamed, you will face effectively a cache miss on everything which could result in a big performance problem.